# How can I use real valued labels in training a CVAE?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, conditional-probability, autoencoders

The Conditional Variational Autoencoders (CVAE) (and other classification networks) I have come across use a one hot vector encoding for labeling categorial data sets.

In my case, I do not have a categorial data set. I have 2 vectors, `states` and `costs` which both contain floating point values. `states` has dim 4 and `costs` has dim 3. I want to train my CVAE in such a way that at test time I feed the decoder a `states` vector and it should output an approximate `costs` vector.

In other words my decoder should return: `p(costs|states,z)`

How should I train and organise my CVAE in this case? Should I simply concat both vectors? What kind of activations should I use? For the reconstruction loss I am using an L2.

This is the current structure of my CVAE [image: CVAE structure]

Comment: I don't use CVAEs, but I think that describing your application more in detail (which real-world problem you are trying to solve, what are your data and how they were collected, how you expect `costs` and `states` to be related, etc.) may help someone experienced in CVAEs to answer.